# Elegant way to include only published posts with get_objects_in_term()?

Tags: posts, taxonomy, publish, get-post

The obvious way is to iterate through the resulting array of IDs, get_post for each and test against `post_status == 'publish'`. But I wonder whether this could cause memory issues since `get_post` will attempt by default to cache each result? Short of a custom SQL join, are there any surprise args one can pass to `get_objects_in_term()` or is there some other tax function I'm not leveraging that I should be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add `'post_status'     => 'publish'` in your query to retrieve only objects with status publish , this will work for `get_posts`, `query_posts` or `$wp_query`  and to include also custom taxonomies you can use `tax_query` in your args list

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The issue I'm wrestling with is the cacheing, which will definitely occur if we use WP_Query in any of its forms. get_objects_in_term() is much more lean because it's only returning post IDs. On the downside, you can't pass it any post_status parameters in the arguments. alas.

Answer (score 2):

There's no arguments you can pass in.  The only argument that does get used is `order`.  Here's the source of the function:

```
<?php
function get_objects_in_term( $term_ids, $taxonomies, $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_array( $term_ids ) )
        $term_ids = array( $term_ids );

    if ( ! is_array( $taxonomies ) )
        $taxonomies = array( $taxonomies );

    foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
            return new WP_Error( 'invalid_taxonomy', __( 'Invalid taxonomy' ) );
    }

    $defaults = array( 'order' => 'ASC' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

    $order = ( 'desc' == strtolower( $order ) ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

    $term_ids = array_map('intval', $term_ids );

    $taxonomies = "'" . implode( "', '", $taxonomies ) . "'";
    $term_ids = "'" . implode( "', '", $term_ids ) . "'";

    $object_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT tr.object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ($taxonomies) AND tt.term_id IN ($term_ids) ORDER BY tr.object_id $order");

    if ( ! $object_ids )
        return array();

    return $object_ids;
}
```

You can, however, copy the function and add in an additional clause to use the post status.

```
<?php
function wpse29749_get_objects_in_term( $term_ids, $taxonomies, $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_array( $term_ids ) )
        $term_ids = array( $term_ids );

    if ( ! is_array( $taxonomies ) )
        $taxonomies = array( $taxonomies );

    foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
            return new WP_Error( 'invalid_taxonomy', __( 'Invalid taxonomy' ) );
    }

    $defaults = array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'order' => 'ASC' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

    $order = ( 'desc' == strtolower( $order ) ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

    $term_ids = array_map('intval', $term_ids );

    $taxonomies = "'" . implode( "', '", $taxonomies ) . "'";
    $term_ids = "'" . implode( "', '", $term_ids ) . "'";

    $object_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT ID from $wpdb->posts WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT tr.object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
            AS tr INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt
            ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
            WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ($taxonomies) 
            AND tt.term_id IN ($term_ids)
        ) AND post_status = %s
        ORDER BY ID $order", $post_status ) );

    if ( ! $object_ids )
        return array();

    return $object_ids;
}
```

Not much different.  An additional element in the `$defaults` as well as some modifications to the SQL.